# Could you tell me what "temporal" is?

Tags: difference

> People don’t usually think of touch as a temporal phenomenon.

(I only have this sentence)

As I know, 'temporal' means two things:

1. relating to the world, 2. relating to the time.

Comment: Well, temporal certainly means worldly or non-spiritual. But relating to human body, like corporeal, it could perhaps be hinting at carnal cravings?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. People don’t usually think of touch as a temporal phenomenon, but it is every bit as time-based as it is spatial.

Comment: @Brandon - I thought you said "I only have this sentence", but it seems to have grown.

Comment: @Brandon - related to time, not related to 'the time'.

Comment: @Brandon - it is bad faith to not quote the source.

Comment: The meaning seems completely clear once the full sentence is known. I'm no longer sure of the reason for your confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quoted text is the first part of a paragraph on page 59 of "Intelligence" by Jeff Hawkins with Sandra Blakeslee (2004). The remainder of the paragraph **explains perfectly** what 'temporal' means in this context. Basically, it means 'time-related' or 'not instant', and in this context, 'having a time- as well as space-related aspect'.

> **People don't usually think of touch as a temporal phenomenon, but it
> is every bit as time-based as it is spatial.** You can carry out an
> experiment to see for yourself. Ask a friend to cup his hand, palm
> face up, and close his eyes. Place a small ordinary object in his
> palm, anything will do - a ring, an eraser, and ask him to identify it
> without moving any part of his hand. He won't have a clue other than
> weight and maybe gross size. Then tell  him to keep his eyes closed
> and move his fingers over the object. He'll most likely identify it at
> once. By allowing the fingers to move, you've added time to the
> sensory perception of touch. There's a direct analogy between the
> fovea at the center of your  retina and your fingertips, both of which
> have high acuity. So touch, too, is like a song. Your ability to make
> complex use of touch, such as buttoning your shirt or unlocking your
> front door in the dark, depends on continuous time-varying patterns.

[Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Qg2dmntfxmQC&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=%22People%20don%E2%80%99t%20usually%20think%20of%20touch%20as%20a%20temporal%20phenomenon%22&source=bl&ots=6lynK5PtkX&sig=ACfU3U0CPmKtPCIgj4YAXs6GS8lklAINsA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjCvOSU5o_uAhXRyIUKHR5DBr8Q6AEwAXoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22People%20don%E2%80%99t%20usually%20think%20of%20touch%20as%20a%20temporal%20phenomenon%22&f=false)